# Как данные поместить в объект (после парсинга строки)?

Tags: java

Есть строка "Boy: Height=56, Weight=43, Hobby=Football";
Есть класс

```
public class Boy {
   private int height;
   private int weight;
   private String hobby;
}
```

То есть вначале надо распарсить строку, как полученные данные поместить в объект  класса Boy?

```
public Boy getValue(String text) { 
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":"); 
   String [] arr =pattern.split(text); 
   Boy boy = new Boy(); 
   if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Boy")){ 
      arr = text.trim().split("=|,|:| "); 
      switch (arr[2]){ 
         case "Height": 
            boy.setHeight(Integer.parseInt((arr[3]));
         case "Weight": 
            boy.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(arr[5])); 
         case "Hobby": boy.setHobby(arr[7]); 
      } 
   } 
   return boy; 
}
```

Comment: Передать полученные данные в конструктор класса.

Comment: Либо описать get/set для каждого поля класса

Comment: Если конструктора в классе нет и нет внешних полей - рефлексия поможет вам. Вопрос толкько зачем вам такой класс тогда))

Comment: Использовал get/set и значения приходили как 0.00 (Это учитывая, что делал Double.parseDouble)

Comment: Покажите как парсили. Хотя зачем double, если у вас поля типа int?

Comment: public  Boy getValue(String text){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":");
        String [] arr =pattern.split(text);
        Boy boy = new Boy();
        if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Boy")){
          arr = text.trim().split("=|,|:| ");
          switch (arr[2]){
              case "Height":
               boy.setHeight(Integer.parseInt((arr[3]));
              case "Weight": 
                  boy.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(arr[5]));
              case "Hobby":
                  boy.setHobby(arr[7]);
          }
       }
        return boy;
    }

Comment: Нечитаемо же. Добавьте код в текст вопроса (кнопка "править").

Comment: Что не получается распарсить строку?

Comment: Да, видимо не получается

Answer (score 2):

Для начала можете создать нужный конструктор:

```
public class Boy {

    public Boy(int height, int weight, String interests) {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.interests = interests;
    }

    private int height;
    private int weight;
    private String interests;
}
```

И далее:

```
String s = "Boy: Height=56, Weight=43, Hobby=Football";
// как-то парсите строку
Boy boy = new Boy(heightFromString, weightFromString, hobbyFromString);
```

Либо сделайте поля публичными (делать так не стоит, дабы следовать ООП).
Либо можете использовать рефлексию, как подсказали в комментариях, но я уверен, что это вам не нужно.